# Anyway for a mediawiki page to have multiple display titles?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

For e.g. I have one page called "Tomato", and I have two categories, one is called "Vegetable", and the other one is called "Shape", and I have the page "Tomato" under both two categories. Now when I open category "Vegetable", I want to see the page showing as "Tomato" in the list, and when I open "Shape" category I want to see the page showing as "Round" in the list (if somewhere the "Round" value can be associated to the page/category), is this possible?

Comment: Not off the shelf but it probably wouldn't be too hard for an extension to use [category sort keys](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Categories#Sort_key) to change the name displayed on the category page.

Comment: Is seems that what you really want is a semantic property (`[[Shape::Round]]`), not a category. See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_MediaWiki.

Comment: Thank you all. I decided to use REDIRECT to get around this, works ok so far.